# Angular-How to change css property of parent div container for one child

Tags: html, css, angular

app.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

child1.componet.html:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary ">
  <div class="panel-heading">
........
</div>
</div>
```

child1.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tb-child1',
  templateUrl: './child1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child1.component.css']
})
```

app.component.css:

```
.container{
width:1200px
}
```

I want the container width should be 1500px for only child1. Is there any way to change that?.

Comment: if you want 1500px for child1 then add a subclass for the container and apply css in child1.component.css

Comment: I have tried that but still not working..can you give me one example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can override the parent class in Child's css class by disabling the view encapsulaion like below in my child component

```
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try like this

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="container subclass">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

In your **child1.component.css** add the below code

```
.container.subclass {width: 1500px !important;}
```

Comment: I've added !important in the css. Please check.

Comment: you could use `ViewEncapsulation` concepts